# Access 2013 VBA Code To Check if a Value Exists in a Query

Tags: vba, if-statement, statements

I have an application with a text box and a sub-form. The sub-form shows the results of a query. I want to be able to type in a value in the text box and see if that value exists in a certain column of a query.

I then want to put this into an IF statement.

```
If
    txtbox1.text matches value in query
    then run regular routine.
Else
    msgbox"This serial number does not exist in this query."
End If
```

Comment: What is you query result being stored in? A recordset? A label? An array?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the result is stored.  You say it is in a subform but that doesn't explain exactly how it is stored.

For example if you did your query and simply dumped it into a label on the subform, you could check the label caption with instr().

```
If instr(label1.caption, txtbox1.text) > 0 then
    then run regular routine.
Else
    msgbox"This serial number does not exist in this query."
End If
```

If you are pulling your query into and ADODB recordset. You can use a filter.

```
rs.filter = ""
rs.filter = "FieldName=" & textbox1.text 'For numeric
rs.filter = "FieldName='" & textbox1.text & "'" 'For alpha numeric

If rs.Recordcount > 1 then
    then run regular routine.
Else
    msgbox"This serial number does not exist in this query."
End If
```

Comment: This is a select query, and the subform is simply showing the results on a form with a text box and button. So the data is not being stored anywhere. Once I re-run the query, the results will change, causing the subform to re-query.